# How can I register a component locally passing props directly vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue.js and in my case I would like to pass props values to the component when registering locally:

Let say I have these two components and app.component.vue expects a props call **title**.

```
import AppComponent  from '@/components/app/app.component.vue'
import AppButton     from '@/components/button/button.component.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<AppComponent/>',
  components: {
AppComponent, 
 AppButton}
})
```

How can I pass **title** props at the registration level of AppComponent ?

```
   components: {
    AppComponent, 
    }
```

I don't wanna wait until the following point to pass the props :

```
<app-component :title="My title"><app-component>
```

Comment: why do you need that ? you could use component life cycle hooks to update the prop

Comment: That's some good thought... for a certain reason I cannot pass props to child compontents  because it is being passed to the other component from the parent as variable AppComponent not as <app-component :title="My title"><app-component> so the only way I can change some values of the child component (AppComponent) is if I can be able to do it when registering it locally as far as I saw.

Comment: What about factory component pattern? https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-single-file-component-factory/